# Converting a string contents to code of the current class?

Tags: java

I know there is already many question about turning a string into runnable code, but my question is a little different. Lets say you have a class with a method called: `public boolean isSame(boolean a, boolean b)`, and a String that contains: `"if(a == b) { return true; } return false"`. Is there a way to add the contents of the string to the code of the method? So the final result will be:

```
public boolean isSame(boolean a, boolean b){
    if(a == b){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Edit: I totally understand if this is not possible, but it is worth asking :).

Comment: There is a way. Are you familiar with the `javac` java compiler and writing custom `ClassLoader`s?

Comment: Are you going to try to interpret and call this method, or are you just generating source code that you can compile later?

Comment: It is possible, just complicated (thankfully; if it was easy, people would use it more; hint: `var img = eval("image"+i)`).

Comment: @JanDvorak I am sorta familiar with both the `javac` and writing a custom `ClassLoader`, but I only have done it once or twice a long time ago. @tieTYT I want to call the method in a try-catch statement.

Comment: Also see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html ; might be what you're looking for (pass it a string, and it will spit out a class file which you then classLoad).

Comment: @JanDvorak But doesn't the string need to include a whole class, not just the "guts" of a method? Also, forgive this 'dumb question', but after a class is loaded, you can use all the methods of the class that is loaded, correct?

Comment: @RandomAwesomeGuy Whatever you compile, it must be a class. Additionally, it should implement an interface that contains the method you will then call (and is available at compile-time).

Comment: Basic structure: `"public class $1 implements Callable<Boolean>{ @override public Boolean call(){"+guts+"}}" => compiler => class loader => `if(test.call()){...`

Comment: @JanDvorak I understand compiling the class and then loading it, but is there another way to do my original question without making a separate class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23821/discussion-between-randomawesomeguy-and-jan-dvorak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use the [BECL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) library - it's a byte code engineering library that, although not renowned for performance, is renowned for ease of use.

**The thing that makes it interesting in your case:**

Unlike other byte code engineering libraries that provide an abstraction on top of byte-code, it works by decompiling a class, weaving in the *required code* and then compiling it again. . . and this happens for the the class loading phase. . . theoretically this would allow you to insert valid code in a string format before or after the original method invocation.

Essentially using the compiler as per suggestions in the comments section of your question, but does a little extra work for you.